# Changing Adaptive Undo Shortcut in System Preferences

Tags: keyboard, catalina, keybindings

I am aware that one can go to **System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts**, and easily change any menu bar shortcut, like Undo, for all applications. This used to work great for me! However this no longer works well in Catalina update, because the Undo command in the menu bar is now smart/adaptive and changes based on what you last did. See below:

[image: Screenshow showing undo command changed to "Undo Typing"]

[image: Screenshow showing undo command changed to "Undo Paste"]

[image: Screenshow showing undo command changed to "Undo Bold"]

[image: Screenshot showing System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts for Undo]

**Question:** What is the new menu bar command for "Undo" that encompasses all variants of "Undo".I already tried, "Undo...". Is their a wildcard like, "Undo*"?

Comment: AFAIK there is no wildcard so you will need to add each variation manually. Or go with the system and learn to use Cmd instead of Ctrl :-)

Comment: Or just leave the shortcuts as they are by default, and then switch Ctrl/Cmd in the keyboard settings.

Comment: @nohillside I think I will do just that! Except for copy/paste... I love Mac, but wish some of the shortcuts were more like KDE/GNOME. I work on Linux, and Mac is similar, except for the keyboard layout :( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts

Comment: @nohillside That is a great suggestion, but I am already aware of this feature. I mapped CTRL -> CAPS-LOCK and OPTION <-> COMMAND to make the layout more KDE/GNOME like. I would not want to map CONTROL <-> COMMAND, as this would mess up my emacs/meta-key usage.

Comment: @nohillside Haha, wish I could convince every employer to give me a Mac. I'll look into making Ubuntu shortcuts more like Mac maybe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the keyboard shortcuts definition doesn't support wildcards, so you'll need to bind every individual menu entry separately.

It might be easier though to switch the meaning of <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> **Keyboard** and leave the shortcuts themselves on <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.