# Disable Cmd-w on macOS Catalina

Tags: keyboard, catalina, shortcut

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> closes the current window on macOS Catalina. This conflicts with my muscle memory of using M-w in Emacs.

I looked at [Disable Command-W in the terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44412/disable-command-w-in-the-terminal), but the accepted answer does not work on macOS Catalina.

How do you disable <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like in old versions, it be can't removed. The work around is the same: the system default can be overridden to a new key combination. The hotkey must be associated with a context menu item name (ie. an app specific menu item). The name must match exactly.

Systems apps use the name `Close` to mean close window, along with iTerm2. Some other apps use the more verbose `Close Window`. Remap both to get decent app coverage. **Note that some apps may use other unique names that mean close window. Separate entries will have to be made for these apps to remap it globally.**

Navigate to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard`.

[image]

Select the `Shortcuts` tab, then `App Shortcuts` in the left pane.

Select the `+` at the bottom of the window to add a new shortcut.

[image]

To remap it globally, select `All Applications` in the `Application` field. To change Cmd-w on a specific application instead of globally, select that instead.

Set `Menu Title` to `Close`. It is case sensitive and must match exactly.

Set `Keyboard Shortcut` to the desired key combination. I set it to an obscure value so it's essentially 'disabled'.

Click `Add` to finalize the key shortcut. The right pane should now show a new entry for `Close` with your key combination (see the first image for an example).

Add another hotkey entry with `Application` set to `All Applications` and `Menu Title` set to `Close Window` for additional coverage.

Close the menu.

The change takes effect immediately, including with open apps.

Comment: That will only work in Apps where the menu item literally says 'Close', not for Close Window, Close Tab, .. etc Looking at the linked question, it pretty much says the same thing - you must have an exact match.

Comment: That's not my experience. It appears to work on all apps, even when they do not list `Close` in their menu.

Comment: Empirically, it has long been proven not to work with 'contextual' menu entries. There are many questions on it - one example https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387276/changing-adaptive-undo-shortcut-in-system-preferences If you did get it to work, I'd love to know what's different from everyone else's experience.

Comment: Ah, I see that all the apps I've tried it on have a `Close` option somewhere in their menus. It seems that "Close" is very common (including system apps). "Close Window" seems to be used with Chrome, which I assume is what is bringing a lot of readers. I'll update the response to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for checking :) btw, you shouldn't need to re-launch an app to see the behaviour change, it should pretty much be 'live' as you change the control panel.