# How to stop command-W from closing iTerm2 when it's active instead of the Python plots I'm intending to close?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, python, iterm

I regularly run Python scripts from an iTerm2 command window, and the scripts usually generate several plots. I have an IDE open as well.

From time to time I end up accidentally closing the iTerm window with a command-W **instead of closing Python's matplotlib windows that I'm targeting.**

If I've had too much coffee I may end up doing this a few times in an afternoon.

I don't see any useful function that closing an iTerm2 window with command-W would ever serve me, so I'd like to inhibit it's closing power on iTerm2.

Under iTerm2/Preferences/Closing I see some options to require confirmation upon command-Q, but there seems to be nothing that addresses command-W under any menu item.

**Question:** How can I stop command-W from closing iTerm2 when it's active instead of the Python plots I'm intending to close?

Alternatively, if there's a way to get the closed window back somehow (since it doesn't seem to be gone; if the script used a lot of memory it remains allocated even when the window is closed) that would certainly at least help.

[image: iTerm2 preferences]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Command-W in the terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44412/disable-command-w-in-the-terminal) - basically you just override the shortcut to be something else.

Comment: Also related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/44412/151404 - I see a comment suggesting CMD+Z will restore the closed window in iterm.

Comment: @JBallin yes it does, and I can't understand why it didn't display at the top when I was getting ready to post. Thanks!  And thanks for the undo (CMD+Z) hint, which could have been a useful answer post to this question but not the duplicate. "Alternatively, if there's a way to get the closed window back somehow..."

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I actually meant to also link this related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/390234/151404

Comment: @JBallin This is the first time I've seen undo operate on a window closing, i.e. I've never seen "unclose" before!

Comment: Agreed. Command Shift T would likely be more intuitive, like the browser shortcut. Btw I don't see a question for "how do I reopen a closed iterm tab" - if you're interested in creating & answering that as a separate question.

Comment: @JBallin Oh, the comments under the answer show that now we must use "Close" and not "Close Window". https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSWRi.png

Comment: You map shortcuts to whatever the action is named in the menu bar.

Comment: @JBallin and need to use the name of the action in 2022 and not the name of the action in 2012

Comment: Your screenshot is for Terminal.app, not iTerm - the action names are set by each app.

Comment: @JBallin I disagree. iTerm2 is the only command window I use, see this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTHgG.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139602/discussion-between-jballin-and-uhoh).